# Android:Inflate exception

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

So I've been following the Wrox book on how to learn android and have gotten to the part on how to obtain results from an Activity and got the error

```
11-10 15:50:31.145: E/AndroidRuntime(528): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-10 15:50:31.145: E/AndroidRuntime(528): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.activites/com.example.activites.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class EditTest
```

So now I now that the EditTest in my xml below is causing the error but I don't know why.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Please enter you name" />
<EditTest
    android:id="@+id/txt_username"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_OK"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="OK" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the class that is unable to start.

```
package com.example.activites;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String tag = "Events";
    int request_Code = 1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(tag, "In the onCreate() event");
    }



    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (keyCode== KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER)
        {
            startActivityForResult(new Intent("com.example.ACTIVITY2"),request_Code);
        }
        return false;

    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if(requestCode == request_Code){
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                Toast.makeText(this, data.getData().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help. I'm sure this is a simple solution I'm just very new to the platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm surprised it compiled:

```
<EditTest
```

I think you mean `<EditText`